# Errors Upgrading SBT

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I am attempting to upgrade my Scala Play Framework application to 2.8, and this involves upgrading SBT to 1.x.

In my **build.propeties** I have `sbt.version=1.3.5`

In **plugins.sbt** I have

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.7.4")
```

However, I see the following:

```
[warn] insecure HTTP request is deprecated 'http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases'; switch to HTTPS or opt-in as ("typesafe-releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases").withAllowInsecureProtocol(true)
[warn] insecure HTTP request is deprecated 'http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases'; switch to HTTPS or opt-in as ("typesafe-releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases").withAllowInsecureProtocol(true)
[warn] insecure HTTP request is deprecated 'http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases'; switch to HTTPS or opt-in as ("typesafe-releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases").withAllowInsecureProtocol(true)
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin:2.7.4 (sbtVersion=1.0, scalaVersion=2.12)
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:2.7.4
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/sbt-plugin_2.12_1.0/2.7.4/sbt-plugin-2.7.4.pom
[error]   not found: /Users/Neil/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.7.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: /Users/Neil/.activator/repository/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.7.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: /usr/local/activator-1.3.6/repository/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.7.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: http://dl.bintray.com/heroku/sbt-plugins/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.7.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: http://dl.bintray.com/neomaclin/maven/com/typesafe/play/sbt-plugin_2.12_1.0/2.7.4/sbt-plugin-2.7.4.pom
[error]   download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target) while downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.7.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target) while downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.7.4/ivys/ivy.xml
```

Here are my resolvers:

```
resolvers += Resolver.typesafeRepo("releases")
resolvers += Resolver.typesafeIvyRepo("releases")
resolvers += Resolver.sbtPluginRepo("releases")
resolvers += Resolver.url("heroku-sbt-plugin-releases", url("http://dl.bintray.com/heroku/sbt-plugins/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
resolvers += Resolver.bintrayRepo("neomaclin", "maven")
```

What's causing all these warnings about using https? More importantly, when I look up those `ivy.xml` files, I get 404s but obviously those PKIX errors in the console. Why am I getting those when I am not behind a proxy? I guess I am using the wrong coordinates, but I can't figure out how they are wrong.

Comment: Do you maybe have custom resolvers on http?

Comment: Good call on getting me to add my resolvers to the question. Anyway, that shouldn't be the case except for that Heroku one since I am calling methods on `Resolver`

Comment: Did you solve this - I have the exact same problem :-(

Comment: Upgrade your JDK as I describe in my self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me was upgrading my JDK to 11 because that version of Java has the certificates in its trust store necessary to make the requests SBT wants to make.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid these errors make sure you have permissions to the repositories you require access to. Furthermore, ensure your sbt credential files contain your credentials used to access these repositories. There are various ways of setting this up, either through IntelliJ `preferences > build, Execution, Deployments > sbt` or `~/.sbt/.credentials`.